# Looking Glass script

Tags: cisco, bgp

Can you recommend good and secure looking glass scripts with traceroute,ping and bgp?
I want to install it to my website, and connect to Cisco routers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much it is secure, but [this one](http://wiki.version6.net/LG) is pretty good.
Demo [here](http://lg.version6.net/).

Answer (score 1):

There are several Looking Classes out there, I'd suggest

- http://racktables.org/mrlg/
- http://www.op-sec.us/mrlg/source/ (Used by DE-CIX)
- http://freshmeat.net/projects/mrlg4php/

Answer (score -1):

If you use RANCID for your configuration backups (and if you don't backup router configurations, RANCID is a great place to start!) it comes with a Looking Glass program that you can easily lock down with appropriate privilege-levels on Cisco.

If you don't already use RANCID, you can find it here: http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/