# How to get ip prefixes from children of given as number?

Tags: ip, routing, whois, nslookup, bgp

So, for example I have as number as10282 how I can get ip prefixes of children for the given as number?

[bgp lookup tool](https://www.dan.me.uk/bgplookup?asn=13046&include_downstream=on)

Given tool is exactly what I need (with ticked include downstream prefixes), but I need to implement it in my application, how to do this? I tried with parsing ripe output of "whois" query but I did not get far, because I do not get always same output I used query (whois -B -h whois.ripe.net -i mb NAME)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/40599/looking-glass-script

Comment: well as I posted in question, I already found lookup tool that does this, but I don't know how to do it on my own. If there is any help, I would appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a view like this of the live BGP global network, you will need your own actual BGP feed.  Looking in RIPE or other databases will only show you what people have been assigned, not what they're actually announcing right now.  i.e, you can't do this 'yourself', you need an external source of data.